# Function not working during form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Why isn't `alert('hi')` working at all when submit button is clicked?

`evt.preventDefault();` & `evt.stopPropagation();` is to prevent the form from trying to open another window. However even when I remove these lines my function still isn't called...

```js
'use strict';
function handleSubmission(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  
  alert('hi');
}

var form = document.querySelector('#formID');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmission);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="formID">
      
      input <input type="text">
      
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not getting any errors in the console.

**EDIT:** To add to the confusion even more. The snippet above doesn't work on Stack Overflow or in my local (chrome) browser. However, on jsfiddle the alert fires just fine... https://jsfiddle.net/jpazrjt4/1/

Comment: `evt.stopPropogation` doesn't sound right, likely that clogs up everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a SO snippet that provides a means to accomplish this with pure Javascript, but it will not behave correctly as when you click Run Code Snippet.

I would like to address your concern about it not working in SO Snippet.  SO snippet does not allow for form submission in the their iframe sandbox.  If you run the SO snippet while in Chrome and then open up developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), you will see in the console log entry

> Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Jsfiddle does not restrict the allow-forms permission for their constructed iframes.  Here is the JSFiddle link so you can test it out: [jsFiddle:jsFormIntercept](https://jsfiddle.net/mrizzo99/t5ooehnk/)

```js
(function() {
"use strict";

   window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   document.getElementById("formID").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
   alert('hi');
 }, false);
   }, false);
 }());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="formID">
      
      input <input type="text">
      
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the tinkering. Just found this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339479/advise-that-submit-events-on-forms-does-not-work-on-code-snippets. It should be noted that my code does in fact work fine on my local machine upon checking again. May have initially been a typo and the fact that SO blocked forms threw me off. Your answer works so I'll accept. However for future readers: I didn't actually need to change my code at all to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to write the below code as `evt.preventDefault()` & `evt.stopPropagation()` both have different functioning

```
'use strict';
function handleSubmission(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Isn't the main problem that `evt.stopPropogation` is misspelled here?

Comment: @Pekka웃 really sorry about that:)

Comment: Your code works on jsfiddle but not SO snippets... https://jsfiddle.net/jpazrjt4/. Infact my ORIGINAL code works in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jpazrjt4/1/. Is this possibly a limitiation of SO snippets?

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation are jQuery functions and r valid only when using the jquery libs.

I cannot seem to find a vanila JavaScript way to acheive that so you will have to use jquery for now

JS as:

```
    function handleSubmission(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropogation();

  alert('hi');
}

var form = document.querySelector('#formID');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmission);
```

and HTML as:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="post" id="formID">

      input <input type="text">

      <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
  </body>
</html
```

Passed the test

Comment: This doesn't work on my local machine...not sure if it would work in a snippet here either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when clicked the button will display a an alert say HI and that submit will not go anywhere because of event.preventDefault()

Answer (score -1):

cool change you code to this and please call jquery before this because stoppropogation is a part of jquery library
May be this will not work here but please check it on your side on codepen etc. it is working
check here:-
http://codepen.io/ermayankrajput/pen/VPXKdN

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="formID">
      
      input <input type="text">
      
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
      
    </form>
<script>
'use strict';
var form = document.getElementById('formID');
form.addEventListener('submit',function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  alert('hi');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Even my exact original code works on codepen and jsfiddle. Just not here in snippets - or in my browsers run on my local machine.